# How to use "contains" or "like" in a dynamic linq query?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic

The help file that came with Dynamic Linq in the CSharpSamples.zip does not show any examples of using contains or like.

Are there any simple workarounds for doing this? i.e where (col like @col) doesn't work.

Comment: Please note everyone I am discussing the DYNAMIC LINQ that comes with Visual Studio in the examples file. In this version, I can define a where query using a string "mycol = @mycol". I know of the simple cases.

Comment: What I'd *really* like to do is insert the string "Like" in place of the "=" in my string and have the Dynamic Linq to parse it. But, I'll take a work around. I think the reason it was not added is they built their parser on System.Linq.Expressions which doesn't have this method.

Comment: To be clear, I can do this

"UserName = @0,Contact.FirstName = @1"

But not this 

"UserName like @0,Contact.FirstName like @1"

Where these are strings, and using Dynamic LINQ syntax:

dc.table.where(mystring, array)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here is the answer! The Dynamic Linq does support the . operator,

According to the docs:

> "Instance field or instance property
>   access. Any public field or property
>   can be accessed."

Thus, it is possible to use this syntax

```
.Where("MyColumn.Contains(@0)", myArray)
```

Thanks for all the suggestions! And thanks to me for finding the solution.

Comment: How can I do that on a nullable column?

Comment: @Teddy
.Where("MyColumn != null && MyColumn.Contains(@0)", myArray)

Comment: How do you convert a Grid `FilterExpression` to this syntax? There are some NuGet Dynamic LINQ libraries, including .NET 4.0 support... do we know if any have added conversion support from LIKE to Contains (or other)?

Comment: Yeah, you better check for null once SQL Server permanently switches on ANSI_NULLs in a future release (2016?).  `x not like '%something%'` and `x like '%something%'` will BOTH evaluate to false when x is null, because the result of the comparison in both cases is unknown.  Very unintuitive.  Alternatively, null-coalese your fields to an empty string before comparing like so: `(MyColumn ?? "").Contains(@0)`, which LINQ will hopefully translate to the SQL ISNULL function call before the 'like' comparison.

Comment: I wonder if I can use this in a computed column for a search?   I would like to use the above syntax in a Select call, so I can return Boolean columns telling me whether the value contains a search term.

Comment: How can we do that case insensitive?

Answer (score 12):

For me the solution was **outerIt**.

```
   class User { public string Name { get; set; } }
   ...
   IQueryable<User> query = db.Users;
   ...
   query = query.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.Name)", list);
```

Note that *outerIt* is kind of a **keyword built in the library** (you don't need to modify it as you can read it in an answer here). You can access the property of your query's type through it.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is *direct* support for the like operator in Linq2Sql:

```
db.MyTable.Where(a => SqlMethods.Like(a.Name, "%"+searchTerm+"%"))
```

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods_members.aspx

... but I prefer using startsWith, endsWith and contains for most applications.