# SQL Like keyword in Dynamic Linq

Tags: dynamic, linq-to-sql, sql-like

I want to use SQL's Like keyword in dynamic LINQ.

The query that I want to make is like this

```
select * from table_a where column_a like '%search%'
```

Where the column_a can be dynamically changed to other column etc

In this dynamic LINQ

```
var result = db.table_a.Where( a=> (a.column_a.Contains("search")) );
```

But the column can't be dynamically changed , only the search key can

How do we create a dynamic LINQ like

```
var result = db.table_a.Where("column_a == \"search\"");
```

That we can change the column and the search key dynamically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2456070/1193727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an ExtensionMethods class with this function

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Like<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string keyword)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
        string number = "Int";
        if (property.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith(number))
            return source;

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var constant = Expression.Constant("%" + keyword + "%");
        MethodCallExpression methodExp = Expression.Call(null, typeof(SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }), propertyAccess, constant);
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodExp, parameter);
        return source.Where(lambda);
    }
```

And then call it like this:

```
var result = db.table_a.Like("column_a", "%search%");
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
.Where("AColumnName.Contains(@0)", "Criteria")
```

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/09/18/dynamic-string-based-queries-in-linq.aspx

Addition:

Use an expression tree
[How do I create an expression tree to represent 'String.Contains("term")' in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278684/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-to-represent-string-containsterm-in-c)
That is what the dynamic linq library does internally.

Comment: I can't find the SQL's "like" sample in the above link. There is an "equal" sample using "==" though. But it's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a direct translation to SQL for the `LIKE` keyword in LINQ. You could build one if you used expression trees, but I haven't gotten that good yet.

What I do is something like this:

```
using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.MailerName))
    search = search.Where(a => SqlMethods.Like(a.Mailer.Name, string.Format("%{0}%", data.MailerName)));
```

where `search` is the query I'm building and `data` is the object containing the properties that hold the search criteria. I build the query dynamically by listing all of the possible search criteria in this way, which adds the appropriate `Where` methods to `search`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but Another approach is add Extention method that use `Contains` to simulate `Like` keyword as :

```
public static class DbHelpers
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> Like<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
        {
            var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (prop == null || prop.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("Int"))
                return source;

            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");
            Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
            Expression value = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);

            var containsmethod = value.Type.GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
            var call = Expression.Call(property, containsmethod, value);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, parameter);
            return source.Where(lambda);
        }
    }
```

And use of it:

```
var foo = entity.AsQueryable().Like("Name", "bla bla");
```

If send `PropertyName` with type of `int`, the method return original entity that you passed before to it.