# Workaround to take invalid LINQ methods out of the query in generic method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to do the following generic method to search entities in a database:

```
    // 'atributo' is the name of the attribute to search against
    public List<TEntity> buscar<TEntity>(string valor, string atributo) where TEntity : class
    {
        var matches = from m in db.Set<TEntity>()
                      where m.GetType().GetProperty(atributo).GetValue(m, null).ToString().Contains(valor)
                      select m;

        return matches.ToList();
    }
```

Of course I'm getting the exception:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method**

And I know that GetType(), GetProperty() and GetValue() are invalid LINQ methods too.

I can't figure out how to use the invalid methods before the query.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Without your "generic" method L2E could (on the right schema) do an index lookup. With the generic method, you will have to pull the entire table to your method, just to cast *every single value to a string and do a substring match*. This table better have ~10 entries...

Comment: @ChrisPitman Thanks for the idea but some tables could have thousands of entries.

Comment: @Chris Even in the case of such generic methods you can have an database lookup (which might use an index if an appropriate index is defined on the DB), if the expression tree is structured in a way that can be recognized by L2E.

Comment: @JeanHominal I understand, I've written many such query generators. However, this method casts everything to strings, which is already never going to match an index. Even if a column was added that had the string form of the searched values, this is using a substring match, requiring a full text index. It's overly complicated for negative value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the expression tree yourself (dynamic LINQ is overkill for your need):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class YourClass
{
    public static List<TEntity> DoSomething<TEntity>(DbContext db, string valor, string atributo)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var mParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));

        var matches = db.Set<TEntity>()
                        .Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                            Expression.Call(
                                Expression.Convert(
                                    Expression.Property(mParam, atributo),
                                    typeof(String)
                                    ),
                                "Contains",
                                new Type[0],
                                Expression.Constant(valor)
                                ),
                            mParam
                         ));

        return matches.ToList();
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. That will not work if the property is not defined on TEntity (even if TEntity is abstract and all subclasses *do* define the property);
2. If the return type of the property is known to be `String`, you can avoid the `Expression.Convert` call;
3. That will not work if Entity Framework can not convert the value of the property to a string (e.g. if the property returns an entity type);

Comment: Thanks. I feel that you are very close. Got the following exception: **Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration**. I'm trying to make it work.

Comment: @user1537004: Whoops. I forgot to use the `mParam` object for the lambda function definition.

Comment: Thanks Jean. It's working perfectly now! Thanks for taking your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

linq to entities translate the linq to an expression tree and then tries to translate that expression tree to SQL. It does not evaluate the expressions and it therefor can't translate reflective code to SQL. What you could do is use [dynamic linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455659/how-to-use-contains-or-like-in-a-dynamic-linq-query) your code would then be something similar to

```
public List<TEntity> buscar<TEntity>(string valor, string atributo) where TEntity : class
{
    return db.Set<TEntity>()
           .Where(atributo + =".Contains(\"" + valor + "\")")
           .ToList()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Have some errors now but I'll try to fix them. Looks promising. :)

Answer (score -1):

Update:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert(m.GetType().GetProperty(atributo).GetValue(m, null))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't working. Got the same exception.

Comment: The exception is slightly different. Now it says: **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method**

Comment: -1: There is no overload of [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert.aspx) that takes an `object` parameter, so that code will not compile.