# IQueryable type to an Array

Tags: linq, iqueryable, dynamic-linq

I have a dynamic Linq query like this. I need to convert the result set into an array. But I am not able to convert the IQueryable type to an Array. Any suggestion?

**my code:-**

```
var query = Data.AsEnumerable()
                .AsQueryable()
                .Select("new(it[\"Country\"] as Country)", "it")
                .Take(10);

foreach (string str in query) // **getting error Unable to cast object of type 'DynamicClass1' to type 'System.String**
{

}
```

I fixed it using like this :- foreach(var str in query) .

But I have another issue now. I have added where condition to the query. Now i am getting error "**No property or field 'Country' exists in type 'DataRow'**".
 following is my query

```
 var query= Data.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().Where("Country = @0", "London").Select("new (Country as Country)");
```

Comment: What is the query supposed to return? Explain what `string str` is for.

Comment: `AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()` seems to be so bad idea...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I fixed it using like this :- foreach(var str in query) . But I have another issue now. I have added where condition to the query. Now i am getting error "No property or field 'Country' exists in type 'DataRow'". following is my query                            var query= Data.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().Where("Country = @0", "London").Select("new (Country as Country)");

Comment: please, update your question with the latest code you tried and state what the problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Dynamic LINQ` all extensions returns collection with `dynamic` elements, so you need change your code for example like this

```
foreach (dynamic str in query) 
{
    ....
}
```

also for your case `str` is object with field `Country`

**UPDATE**
for question from comment
if Data is `DataTable` when you call `AsEnumerable` or `AsQueryable` you work with collection of `DataRow`, so when you want filter it by column value you need use syntax for `DataRow` like this

```
Data.AsQueryable().Where("it[\"Country\"] = @0", "London")
```

or you can do select first like that

```
var query= Data.AsQueryable()
               .Select("new (it[\"Country\"] as Country)")
               .Where("Country = @0", "London")
```

**UPDATE2**
until you don't specify type for field it can be `Object` so you need change `Select` clause like this

```
....
.Select("new(Convert.ToString(it[\"Country\"]) as Country)")
....
```

in this case when you call `Where` after `Select` field `Country` will is `String`, so `String` have `Contains` method

Comment: One more doubt. I have changed the query to      var data = Data.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().Select("new (it[\"Country\"] as Country)").Where("Country.Contains(@0)", "L"); . Now i am getting error "No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Object'" . Any help?

Comment: I have seen like it should work                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455659/how-to-use-contains-or-like-in-a-dynamic-linq-query . Is it because my data contain null records as well?

Comment: thanks. that did the trick. that was basic, i should have try before posting the issue. thanks anyway :)